# What is the acl tag in Stanford dependency parsing?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

An `acl` tag appears in Stanford dependency parses with no explanation in the manual. For example, a sentence like "are you going there" you gives something like:

```
root(ROOT-0, are-1)
nsubj(are-1, you-2)
acl(you-2, going-3)     <--
advmod(going-3, there-4)
```

Can someone explain what this tag is?

Answer (score 12):

This is a new label in the Universal Dependencies representation, documented here: http://universaldependencies.github.io/docs/u/dep/acl.html

From the link:

> acl stands for finite and non-finite clauses that modify a nominal. The acl relation contrasts with the advcl relation, which is used for adverbial clauses that modify a predicate. The head of the acl relation is the noun that is modified, and the dependent is the head of the clause that modifies the noun.

Comment: +1 Great link! But can you please also add a line or two here in the answer? SO discourages link-only answers.